# Punctuation for remarks

Tags: punctuation

What is the correct punctuation for remarks (author's comments)? For example:

*Through the tears* Why are you doing this to me?

Should I use asterisks or brackets with this comment? Do I need to capitalize the first word or not? Should I add closing punctuation after? Please help me understand.

Comment: Hemingway would've disapproved of this way of writing anyway. What good is it if you've to add the redundant *Through the tears* if it isn't obvious without it being explicitly mentioned! Read *For Whom the Bell Tolls* or *A Farewell to Arms* to see what I mean.

Comment: In a script, directions are sometimes italicized *and* parenthesized. Kathy: (*waving*) Goodbye!

Comment: Is it a script or a narrative?